# Before having relations with our non-Muslim spouse, should we say a dua to protect us from evil?

Tags: dua, sex, interfaith

We know that when we are going to have relations with our spouse that we should always say a dua for Allah to protect us from evil.

Question is, how does this work if a Muslim is married to a non-Muslim (but of the people i.e a Christian or Jew)?

- Does he still recite the dua?
- Does he still put his hand over her forehead and recite the dua?
- Does he just say it to himself?

Thank you.

Comment: The "prayer" comes from within your heart and God reads your heart before even you speaking out.

Comment: I'm not sure this is of any relevance here, but I suppose the context suggests this might be of interest: you are allowed to pray for any living person in matters of dunya that don't go against islam (e.g. you can't pray that someone makes a lot of money off prostitution and robbery). What you cannot do is pray for a deceased person in matters of akhira if they weren't muslim - for example, you would not be allowed to pray for Abu Talib if you think he did not die as a muslim, as most scholars do.

Comment: Those dua's are recommended for a Muslim and there's no restriction quoted. And asking Allah is always good. But I'.m afraid you are confusing dua's and situations.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - nope, not confusing dua's and situations. just want to make sure that it is allowed/permissible :) I mean, I am sure there are things you cannot recite to non Muslims, right?

Comment: I'm quite sure you do as the 2nd point is only AFAIK applies (as it is narrated) at the first encounter between you as spouses.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obligatory dua to be recited before having sex regardless of the spouses faith. However, there are many duas that a spouse may recite to get extra reward seeking Allah's forgiveness. I hope the following duas will be useful to you.

Dua to be recited in the first wedding night by the husband:

> When you marry a woman, say: “O Allah, I ask You for the goodness
>   within her and the goodness that you have made her inclined towards,
>   and I seek refuge with You from the evil within her and the evil that
>   you have made her inclined towards.” -- [Duas.com](http://duas.com)

Dua before sexual intercourse:

> In the Name of Allah. O Allah, keep the shaytaan away from us and keep
>   the shaytaan away from what You have blessed us with. -- [Duas.com](http://duas.com/dua/332/dua-before-sexual-intercourse)